# Buttons? what's the rectangle around the letters of the button mean after a click?

Tags: java, swing, button, user-interface

[image: Expl of the focus on the Save Rectangle button]

In java after pressing a button (mouse click) there then appears a rectangle around the text in that button. What does this mean? I have no code in the action performed, and im just wandering what it means, sorry if this is a repeat question but i dont quite know how to rephrase it for a better search.

Comment: Maybe if you post a screenshot it might be clearer...

Comment: It takes 10 rep to post a screenshot, ill put one up when i can for other users

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> In java after pressing a button (mouse click) there then appears a rectangle around the text in that button.

It indicates that the component has focus so it is ready to receive KeyEvents.

All components are designed to indicate when they have focus. For another example, when a text field gains focus you see a blinking Caret.

Comment: Thank you, I was thinking that but i wasn't sure, I felt like i was only going in circles testing code in my program to see if setting Clicks.setFocusable(true); // Clicks being the button, just to see whether I would get a rectangle around the text in the button